# Solving the matrix equation $X^T~ J ~X=\Phi$ under the given metric $J$ with skew-symmetric $\Phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

How do I solve for $X$ in the matrix equation (with $^T$ representing the $transpose$ operation):

> $X^T~ J ~X=\Phi$,

where $X$ is a $2 \times 5$ matrix, "metric" $J_{2\times 2}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1  \\
    -1       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\Phi_{5\times 5}$ being a known anti-symmetric/skew-symmetric square matrix with all real entries?

Answer (score 1):

Since $J$ has rank 2, the equation in question is solvable only if the rank of $\Phi$ is either 0 or 2.

Suppose $\Phi$ is a rank-2 skew-symmetric matrix first. Then there exists a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^T\Phi Q=aJ\oplus 0_{3\times3}$ for some $a\ne0$. Let $Y=XQ=(\mathbf y_1,\mathbf y_2,\ldots,\mathbf y_5)$. The equation in question is then equivalent to $Y^TJY=aJ\oplus 0_{3\times3}$, which amounts to the system of equations
\begin{cases}
\det(\mathbf y_1,\mathbf y_2)=a,\\
\det(\mathbf y_i,\mathbf y_j)=0 \text{ when } i\notin\{1,2\} \text{ or } j\notin\{1,2\}.
\end{cases}
The first equation implies that $\mathbf y_1$ and $\mathbf y_2$ are linearly independent. In turn, the second one implies that $\mathbf y_3=\mathbf y_4=\mathbf y_5=0$. Therefore the general solution is given by $Y=(M,0_{2\times 3})$ or $X=(M,0_{2\times 3})\,Q^T$, where $M$ is any $2\times2$ matrix of determinant $a$.

Next we consider the case $\Phi=0$. By an analogous argument to the above, we see that the general solution is given by any matrix $X$ of rank at most 1.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how to find those $Q$ and $M$ matrices? I have got to deal generally only with rank $2$ $\Phi$'s.

Comment: @VineethBhaskara Do you know how to diagonalise a matrix? If $\Phi$ has rank 2, its square would be $-a^2I_2\oplus 0_{3\times3}$. The columns of $Q$ are just a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of $\Phi^2$.

Comment: Can you please explain how the fact that the metric-like $J$ being of rank $2$ restricts the rank of $\Phi$ to be at most $2$ for the solution to exist? What if you had the identity 2x2 matrix $I$ sitting there instead of $J$?

Comment: A couple of clarifications please: 1) does $(M,0_{2 \times 3})$ mean concatenating the matrix $M$ with the 2x3 all-zero-matrix side-by-side to result in a $2\times 5$ matrix?

Comment: 2) "$M$ can be any $2\times 2$ matrix of det = $a$'' -- means that there are an infinite solutions possible for $X$? But, we have 10 unknowns (elements of $X$) and 10 knowns (upper triangle of $\Phi$) - so having 10 unknowns with 10 equations. Why aren't we then having an unique solution for $X$ in the case where rank of $\Phi$=$2$? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @VineethBhaskara (0) The LHS of your equation is equal to the RHS. If the LHS has rank $\le2$, so does the RHS when the equation is satisfied. (1) Yes, it's an augmented matrix. (2) There're ten determinant conditions in my answer. The first line contains one and the second line contains nine, with $(i,j)=(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)$. But as the answer shows, they actually amount to only seven equations, namely $\det(\mathbf y_1,\mathbf y_2)=a$ and $\mathbf y_3=\mathbf y_4=\mathbf y_5=0$ (entrywise). So the system is actually underdetermined.